# Count values from <input type="text"

Tags: javascript, php

Hello i want to count the ids inside a input type="text"

the values return as this **1,4,6** etc

```
 <input type="hidden" class="selected_ids" value="selected_ids" name="selected_ids[]" multiple="yes" id="selected_ids" />
```

Comment: who can fill a hidden type text ? else you can get the value and split on coma and at last count the length of elements in your new array !

Comment: @Anonymous0day - anyone who can access the DOM using developer tools can fill in a hidden input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use split function. for example :

```
    var curval = document.getElementById('selected_ids').value;
    var curval_arr = curval.split(',');
    var cnt = curval_arr.length;
```

Comment: yes thats was the solution. I didnt point out that i wanted to count via javascript. Thanks Lalji

Comment: Ok just replace following line  var curval = $('#selected_ids').val(); by document.getElementById('selected_ids').value;

Comment: @ Simos Ioannidis Tick mak this answer if it is helpful to you. Thanks

Comment: How do i do that?  I am new at this. Yes it was very helpful

Comment: @ Simos Ioannidis Please check my answer i have updated my answer. just copy from here and paste. It will works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

here the only javascript version :

```js
var testme = function() {
  var myInput = document.getElementById('selected_ids');
  var myValue = myInput.value;
  var myCount = myValue.split(',').length;

  document.body.innerHTML += '<br>myValue = ' + myValue + ' | myCount = ' + myCount;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="selected_ids" value="1,4,6" name="selected_ids[]" multiple="yes" id="selected_ids" />
<button onclick='testme()'>test me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your input type needs to be `text` and not `hidden`. It's not possible to enter values in a hidden text box.

So your text box should be :-

```
<input type="text" class="selected_ids" value="selected_ids" name="selected_ids[]" multiple="yes" id="selected_ids" />
```

Now suppose the user enters `1,4,6` into the text box(make sure the numbers are separated by a comma). Then on the PHP side you can access as follows.

```
<?php
$array = explode(',', $_POST['selected_ids']); //this array consists all the elements.
//To get length, do :-
count($array);
?>
```